# What is the Order for Element/Tags in CSS

Tags: css

I apologize if my question is not correct for this venue. I read the asking help info and did not see where this question could not be asked.

Does it matter what order the HTML elements are in on the CSS stylesheet?
I "googled" my question and most answers said it doesn't matter, a few said different.

Do "divs" and "ids" go before HTML defined tags, "h1-h6", "p", "a", etc. in the CSS code?
The following is my HTML code.
So in the CSS code would I style the "ids" before the HTML defined tags?

```
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Relax and Restore</h1>
                <h3>Breathe</h3>
        </div><!--/#header-->

            <p>Welcome to Calmness</p>

        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a></l1>
                <li><a href="benefits.html" target="_blank">Benefits</a></l1>
                <li><a href="learn-more.html" target="_blank">Learn More</a></l1>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/#nav-->
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this question apart case-by-case:

**Does the ordering matter in a single selector?**
As long as the selector is valid, it doesn't matter.

As a sample:

```
h1#id.class
```

and

```
h1.class#id
```

are both valid and equal selectors and will match the element `<h1 id="id" class="class">`.

The following isn't a valid selector, unless you an element with `id="idh1"`

```
.class#idh1
```

**Does the ordering matter in a single line?**
Very much so.

The following selector

```
.class1 .class2
```

matches all elements that have `class="class2"` that have a parent of `class="class1"` like this:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
    </div>
</div>
```

while the selector

```
.class2 .class1
```

will match the opposite containment

```
<div class="class2">
    <div class="class1">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Does the ordering matter inside the CSS file?**
No, as long as you don't want to override previous rules.

The following are both valid and equal:

```
#id {...}
h6 {...}
```

and

```
h6 {...}
#id {...}
```

**Additional words of advice:**
CSS works from **right to left**. I cannot stress this point enough.
While performance isn't an issue for many style-sheet writers, you will still want to write good code. You never know when you end up working on a very heavy-load web project.
It's better to give elements classes than to style them by their dom element type and their parent.

As a short example, a bad selector:

```
.class1 > *
```

and, with appropriate DOM changes, a better solution:

```
.class1 > .class2
```

The reasoning: the first selector above first selects *every* node in your source and then filters for those with an appropriate parent, the second requires more work in the DOM, but provides noticeably better results if your site is heavy.

As a simple rule of thumb, if you have more than ten of *something*, attach a class to it instead of a node selector.

Answer (score 1):

The order is important. The first elements should be your defaults, like your global DOM elements (p, h1, h2, a, etc).

The lower you put an element it will overwrite whats higher on the sheet. Also, the more specific you target an element, the more likely it will have higher importance. for example,

```
.header .nav p {color:white}
```

will overwrite

```
p {color:red}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right...  no order inside your css file does not matter.  The style it's chosen based on the style's specificity.  Using an id is more specific than using a class.  Using a class is more specific than an element, and so on.  That said, if two rules have the same level of specificity (a common reason for this would be reusing the same class name) the last one defined will be the one used.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes and no. There isn't any defined way you must write the css, in other words you can mix elements (div, p, a, ul), ids (#header, #content) and classes any way you want.

But the order affects how the browser uses your CSS. The browser applies the styles from top to bottom, which means that a style at the beginning of the file will be overwritten by a style in the end of the file.

As [httpgio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21758513/150415) and [neverlucky13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21758681/150415) points out a more specific rule will overwrite more generic rules regardless of the order of the file. Try to keep it simple and create classes rather than styling DOM elements directly, at least until you get a little experience.

If your css file looks like this:

```
<div id="blue" class="red">Blue</div>
<div class="red">Red</div>
```

The first div will have blue text and the second red text

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8w9Zx/)

All of this also applies when you use multiple stylesheets.

Comment: I believe you didn't quite understand the question.

Comment: What's wrong with his answer? I think it's pretty accurate.